# Bash: printing out numbers containing commas to csv file

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I am trying to print out numbers with commas to a csv file using bash.

The command:

```
printf "1,000" > the.csv
```

prints out two cells, one with 1, and one with 000. I would like to know how I tell the csv file to ignore the comma so that I can only have one cell containing 1,000.

Side question: am I able to resize the columns as I print to them? i.e. I print a word that is too long for the cell to fully hold, can I make it just big enough as I print the word?

Comment: CSV does not have the concept of "size"; a column is simply the text between two commas, and it can be however long it needs to be. Your question suggests that you want to affect the formatting of a tool you are using to open and view the CSV; my best guess is that that tool is Excel, and that your shortest route to improved happiness is to get rid of Excel.

Comment: Anyway, please only ask one question per question.

Comment: A CSV cell can contain the seprator; it can contain also, for instance, line breaks and double quotes. You find the definition of the format and how to escape these characters [here](https://techterms.com/definition/csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV requires commas to be in quoted strings. Because the quotes are parsed by the shell, you are not writing literal quotes with your command. If you want to write literal double quotes, the syntax for that would be

```sh
printf \"1,000\" > the.csv
```

or

```sh
printf '"1,000"' > the.csv
```

(The lack of a final newline and the use of a literal string as the first argument to `printf` are problematic for other reasons. You really want

```sh
printf '"%s"\n' "1,000" > the.csv
```

which also makes it easy to write multiple lines if you want to.)